# Closed form for coefficients related to excedance set of permutation

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

Working on suitable closed form for [A329369](http://oeis.org/A329369), I discovered very useful coefficients, which have the following recurrence relation:

$$T(0,1)=T(0,2)=1$$
$$T(n,1)=1, n>0$$
$$T(0,k)=0, k>2$$
$$T(2n+1,k)=kT(n,k)+T(n,k-1)$$
$$T(2n,k)=kT(n,k)+T(n,k-1)-\frac{1}{k-1}(T(2n,k-1)+T(n,k-1))$$

It looks like $T(n,k)$ is always integer.

Also I recognize Stirling numbers of the second kind in $T(2^n-1,k)$.

Is there any way to get a closed form from this recurrence relation?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for comment! Done (also sign was fixed). Please try to compute coefficients again.

Comment: I am not sure whether I got your recurrence right, but if I did, the generating function $T_3(x)$ of $T(n, 3)$ satisfies an equation of the form $p(x)T_3(x^2) + q(x) T_3(x) = r(x)$ for polynomials $p, q, r$ of degree $5$, $4$ and $3$ respectively.

Comment: The number of non-zero $T(n, k)$ for given $n$ is https://oeis.org/A063787, right?

Comment: @MartinRubey, thank you for comment! Number of non-zero $T(n,k)$ for a given $n$ is $\operatorname{wt}(n)+2$ where $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ is the binary weight of $n$ (OEIS A000120). Also I will try to check your first comment later.

Comment: You have certainly looked at the scatterplot http://oeis.org/A329369/graph, which shows nice, quite straightforward self-similar patterns. :)

Comment: @Wolfgang, thank you for comment! I am the author of this sequence. I also did a lot of work to find the simplest formula possible. I think the simplest is the variation of the Gandhi polynomials (see A357990). On the other hand, I also found a closed form alternative to the inverse binomial transformation modulo 2 (see draft for A358612). Can you suggest something even simpler?